# Is it possible for a BMW 120d to have a cracked engine block?

Tags: bmw

The above mentioned vehicle was towed to a reputable workshop on 20 January 2020. The owner Matthew  informed us that the vehicle is losing water.
We pressure tested the vehicle and found that the top radiator hose was burst. We replaced the hose and pressure tested the vehicle again and found exhaust gas in the cooling system, which indicates a blown cylinder head.
The engineer found that the cylinder head was not cracked and was suitable for reinstallation/assembly.
Upon running the vehicle it was clear the vehicle was still building up pressure as before. At this point we decided to replace the EGR cooler as a possible source of the problem. The problem persists. Can the BMW engine block be cracked ?

Comment: Block cracked or porous joint between sleeve and block.

Comment: Anything is possible...

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel.  Yes, this is completely possible.  When the cylinder head was removed and serviced, the block should have been too.  Recommend complete the entire repair, or there is always option of just getting another motor.

Comment: Hi Steven, what is the maximum deviation allowed on an engine block from crest to valley to justify NOT sending in the block to an engineering company for surface grinding ,?

Comment: Not sure Daniel.  Should be checking surface as well as pressure testing internals.   Good luck with it!